# LXC change default non-root user

Tags: permissions, users, lxc

I am running an lxc container for an app, but need to change the default user to the same as my host system. I setup the container following these instructions:

https://blog.simos.info/how-to-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/

Is there a way to change the default non-root user from ‘ubuntu’ to something else e.g. ‘user1’ ?

I tried to add a user in the container, using

```
sudo adduser user1
```

but cant login to it from outside the container:

```
lxc exec gui1604 — sudo –user user1 –login
sudo: /sbin/bash: command not found
```

Preferably, I would like to have the same permissions as the defautlt 'ubuntu' user and the home folder in the container as

```
 /home/user1/…
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by renaming the default user 'ubuntu' to 'user1' with:

```
sudo usermod -l user1 ubuntu
```

And rename the home folder:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/user1 -m user1
```

This gave me all the right privileges and permission. I had to login to the container as root to do this.
Maybe it is better to add another user instead, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but still, you can check: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#yaml-examples

in particular:

```
config:
  user.user-data: |
    #cloud-config
    users:
      - name: your_username
        ... other user params
```